# What does Integer#times.collect mean?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I have such code:

```
users = [ a, b ]
users += 10.times.collect do |i|
  name = "user_#{i}"
  user = User.create(name: name)
end
```

`10.times` seems to return an `Enumerator` object. However, `collect` method does not appear in [ruby-doc Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html), but appears in [ruby-doc Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect). In [ruby-doc Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect), it says `collect` returns `new_ary`. How come `new_ary` is added to `users`?

Comment: Why on earth did you tag this with 'emulator' ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I guess it was a misspelling. I edited.

Comment: Yes. It was a misspelling.

Comment: I see - *enumerator* vs. *emulator*. That was too easy for me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a method from [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect), a module that is included in `Enumerator`.`collect` acts as a `map` function you give a block to it and the result is saved in an array for every item in your `Enumerable` collection.`10.times` returns an `Enumerble` object with the numbers from 0 to 10 (non-inclusive).

Comment: collect does the same as map. Many ruby developers (me included) prefer using collect, as it matches other similar method names: select, detect, reject, and inject.

Comment: @ReggieB By "matches", you mean it rhymes.

Comment: I'm happy with matches.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, always do some `self` introspection. I do so; that's why I am asking you also to do the same. Let's see how I would find out all the connections:

```
[4] pry(main)> enum = 10.times
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
[5] pry(main)> enum.class
=> Enumerator
[6] pry(main)> enum.class.included_modules
=> [Enumerable, Kernel]
[7] pry(main)> enum.method(:collect).owner
=> Enumerable
```

Now, `Enumerable#map` and `Enumerable#collect` are an alias of each other. And once you call them on a collection, they will always return back an `Array`. Really, sometimes you don't need to go to check the documentation, as you can find these out in your *IRB*. Now, for examples and how-this-method-works stuffs, you can seek help from *online doc* or use `ri`.

Comment: @sawa Can I have now your review one more time ? I am done.. :-)

Comment: @sawa  Your edit always makes thing more beautiful.. So I like your edit always.. :-)